# Is it possible to download a picture of specified HTML dom on mobile with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to let my visitor download a specified range of my web page. For example:

```
<div id="content">
  <h4>Sales Report</h4>
  <canvas>....</canvas>
  <img src="..." />
</div>
```

I want my visitor can download a picture with the content of the div#content and save the picture on his/her mobile.

What should I do?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Longer answer: Not sure on iOS, but on Android, one can just long-press the image and save. No JS needed.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer not image but for a bunch of HTML content.